# Logstash Grafana see data in real time

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, grafana

I have a small problem that has been bugging me for days now and don't know exactly how to solve it as I am new to this technology.

I have a windows server 2016 running elasticsearch, logstash and Grafana. Our server onPrem is configured to send data to this server. I configured logstash.conf as follow to retrieve those logs and send them to elastic search and then visualise them in Grafana dashboard.

```
input {
  syslog {
    port => my-port
    codec => cef
    syslog_field => "syslog"
    grok_pattern => "<%{POSINT:priority}>%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}"
 }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
     hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
         index => "logstash_index"
 }
}
```

I know for a fact that I should receive hundreds of data per minute, but when I head to Grafana dashboard, I am able to see max 5 logs in 1 minute range, so I am loosing the other syslog events.

I configured my dashboard to refresh every 20min so I can have an accurate bucket data, but still I am not seeing all of them. as you can see in the screenshot

[image: Grafana logs time]

ideally I would like to see those data flowing in my dashboard in realtime, so I can have all the syslogs.
(when I tried kiwi syslogs software I was able to see those data flowing in realtime, but this Is not happening with EL(k) and Grafana)

I hope I made my thought clear enough, if not so please ask me more info

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you see the data in the ES index?  This seems to be a grok related issue. Can you once verify? If thats not the case, could you show the Grafana query being used?

Comment: The query used in Grafana is a simple one. I am Grouping by Date Histogram based on timestamp. I do believe that Is a grok problem as all the logs visualised in Grafana have a tag _grokparsefailure, I just couldn't find any solution about how to fix this

Comment: ‘grok_pattern => "<%{POSINT:priority}>%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}"’ is where the problem is. Use a grok parser to fix the expression to match the syslog. You can use [grok parser](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/). also check if you might have the data present in ES.